# OpenOffice saves empty cells in xlsx

Tags: excel, xlsx, openoffice-calc

I'm processing xlsx files in PHP. When I create xlsx file using openoffice with just one filled cell, the spreadsheet already has 65536 rows itself. It looks like openoffice stores all cells even if they are empty. Is there any solution I can save only as many rows/columns as they are filled? Because every library for parsing xlsx produces then wrong number of rows so I'm not able to process it correctly. Good solution would be to achieve it directly inside openoffice, or use some external tool/script (*nix based) to clean up such xlsx file if possible.

Comment: It seems that LibreOffice can save as XLSX but OpenOffice cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

Use [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) to open the XLSX and save it with or without modifications.

OpenTBS is a pure PHP tools whose purpose is to merge data with LibreOffice and Ms Office documents using the technique of templates.

Since its version 1.9.0, OpenTBS can handle with XLSX workbooks made with LibreOffice. Such XLSX workbooks may have an extra row definition which contains a repetition attribute that extends it upon the maximum limit of row number. OpenTBS simply reduce this extra extended row into a single row.

- [OpenTBS download page](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php)
- [OpenTBS demo](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo)
- [OpenTBS doc](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?demo)